# Passing down a className to a child component when called from another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a `className` to a child component of `layouts/index.js` in React with Gatsby. How can I pass the className in `props` to be used with the component when the `onClick` is registered in another component?

**index.js**

```
class Template extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      navIsVisible: false,
    }
    this.handleNavIsVisible = this.handleNavIsVisible.bind(this)
  }

  handleNavIsVisible() {
    this.setState({
      navIsVisible: !this.state.navIsVisible
    })
  }
  render() {
  const { children } = this.props

    return (
      <div> 
        <MenuButton navIsVisible={this.handleNavIsVisible}/>
         <div className="page">
           ...
         </div>
         {/* Adding the class here seems to be the best option but does not activate onClick, yet does if adding to a div with Menu contained */}
         <Menu className={`${this.state.navIsVisible ? 'nav-is-visible' : ''}`}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**MenuButton.js** to activate the class `onClick`

```
class MenuButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.menuClick = this.menuClick.bind(this)
  }

  menuClick(){
    this.props.navIsVisible();
  }

  render () {
     return (
        <div className="sticky-menu-button">
            <span onClick={this.menuClick}>Menu</span>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

MenuButton.propTypes = {
    navIsVisible: PropTypes.func,
}
```

Alternatively, within **Menu.js** but unsure how to pass the state change to this component?

Comment: If these components you're talking about have no parent-child relationship or the relationship is very high up, you should look into using the new React context API (it's part of native React, not an npm package). Either that or redux is a good choice https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that out. For the moment being I have added `className={'${this.state.navIsVisible ? 'nav-is-visible' : ''}'}` to a `div` and then changed my CSS to suit the action. I am hoping your suggestion gives me a nicer way of achieving this.

Comment: Can't think of anything nicer. It's personally how I use it. But I don't wrap it in a string literal. I just use a regular ternary. `className={this.state.navIsVisible ? 'nav-is-visible' : ''}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works on a div and not on your Menu component is that when you pass it to a div it adds that class "directly" to the div HTML element but when you pass it to your component it just passes it as a prop. It really depends on what you do inside the render method of the Menu component and what you return from it. If you make sure to grab that prop and attach it to whatever it renders it will work just as it did on a div.

eg:

```
class Menu extends Component {

render () {
  return (
    <div className={this.props.className}>
      <p> Menu Component </p>
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```