# when should I pass 'className' props to react component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Some react components pass the **className** props to the child component.
I haven't seen any need for passing `className` as a prop in my projects.

why this `className` props is been used ? and when should i adopt this approach?

```js
import styled from 'styled-components' 

const ReactComponent = ({ className }) => {
  return <div className={className}/>
}

const StyledComponent = styled(ReactComponent)``;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the context, but generally, the `className` prop is passed down from parent to child to either overwrite, or append the existing `className` on the child component.

This is particularly useful in the scenario when you are building **reusable** base components which needed to be easily extended and customised.

Given your example,

```
const ReactComponent = ({ className }) => {
  return <div className={className}/>
}
```

Let's say we have a parent component which renders the child `ReactComponent`, and we need to customise the stylings for this instance:

```
return (
  <div className='container'>
    <ReactComponent className='is-red' />
    <ReactComponent className='is-blue'/>
  </div>
)
```

This will allow the parent to render both components, with different styles, and without the need to repeat the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You generally add classes to create a style or JavaScript code snippet that effects more than one element. [Here is an explanation of how to use classes](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp).

This particular component uses StyledComponent, but it's possible that the user wanted to add a class to [add extra styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230635/passing-in-class-names-to-react-components) on top of those for the default in specific cases.

It's also possible that the classes are used to [toggle some effect in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284048/passing-down-a-classname-to-a-child-component-when-called-from-another). I've linked examples of each case.

Without more code it's hard to say why this particular user passed down a className, but there are certainly cases where you could want to, or when you could do without passing down a className. If your code doesn't seem to require it, there's definitely no reason to add it in.